# What namespace is IActionCommand in?

Tags: wpf

I found an example of something I want to do here: http://csharprambling.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/true-mvvm-by-implementing-event-triggers-for-non-button-base-controls-in-silverlight/

But for the life of me I can't seem to find out where the heck the IActionCommand<> interface is located and googling it turns up surpisingly little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IActionCommand<T>` is not part of the framework, and likely part of a 3rd party MVVM Library.  (This is a common interface in many libraries, such as [Jounce](http://jounce.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Commands).)

Comment: Ah, that explains it... would have figured that out if I could have seen his using statements I suppose.  In that case, would I be able to modify that example to use without that interface?

Comment: @BrandonMoore Depending on what you're doing, you could just use `ICommand` directly.  The only thing `IActionCommand<T>` seems to do is wrap the command parameter from `object` to `T`...